# Original template code suddenly doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I was translating the titles and sentences right on the editor. I don't know what went wrong, but when I hit upload I keep getting this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Comentários' (T_STRING) in /home2/tkleinow/public_html/wp-content/themes/fashionistas/inc/template-tags.php on line 94
```

Then I tried to copy the original code for that section (template tags) on the zip files, but I keep getting the same error.

I pasted it on Excel to find what the line was, and this is wat I got:

```
<?php printf( __( '%s', 'athemes' ), sprintf( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', get_comment_author_link() ) ); ?>
```

My website was doing just fine, I don't know how I screwed it like that.

This is the whole thing:

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 *
 * Eventually, some of the functionality here could be replaced by core features
 *
 * @package aThemes
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'athemes_content_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable
 */
function athemes_content_nav( $nav_id ) {
    global $wp_query, $post;

    // Don't print empty markup on single pages if there's nowhere to navigate.
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( $post->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
        $next = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

        if ( ! $next && ! $previous )
            return;
    }

    // Don't print empty markup in archives if there's only one page.
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) )
        return;

    $nav_class = ( is_single() ) ? 'post-navigation' : 'paging-navigation';

    ?>
    <nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $nav_id ); ?>" class="<?php echo $nav_class; ?>">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'athemes' ); ?></h1>

    <?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

        <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous"><span>Artigo Anterior</span>%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Link do Post Anterior', 'athemes' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?>
        <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next"><span>Próximo Artigo</span>%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Link para o próximo artigo', 'athemes' ) . '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) ) : // navigation links for home, archive, and search pages ?>

        <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Artigos Anteriores', 'athemes' ) ); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Artigos Recentes <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'athemes' ) ); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </nav><!-- #<?php echo esc_html( $nav_id ); ?> -->
    <?php
}
endif; // athemes_content_nav

if ( ! function_exists( 'athemes_comment' ) ) :
/**
 * Template for comments and pingbacks.
 *
 * Used as a callback by wp_list_comments() for displaying the comments.
 */
function athemes_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

    if ( 'pingback' == $comment->comment_type || 'trackback' == $comment->comment_type ) : ?>

    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class(); ?>>
        <div class="comment-body">
            <?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'athemes' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?> <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'athemes' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class( empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ); ?>>
        <article id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment-body">
            <footer class="clearfix comment-meta">
                <div class="reply">
                    <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'add_below' => 'div-comment', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .reply -->

                <div class="clearfix comment-author vcard">
                    <?php if ( 0 != $args['avatar_size'] ) echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>

                    <div class="comment-metadata">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
                            <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>">
                                <?php printf( _x( '%1$s', '1: date, 2: time', 'athemes' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ); ?>
                            </time>
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

                    <?php printf( __( '%s', 'athemes' ), sprintf( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', get_comment_author_link() ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .comment-author -->

                <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Seu comentário será aprovado assim que passar pela moderação.', 'athemes' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

            <div class="comment-content">
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
            </div><!-- .comment-content -->
        </article><!-- .comment-body -->

    <?php
    endif;
}
endif; // ends check for athemes_comment()

if ( ! function_exists( 'athemes_the_attached_image' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints the attached image with a link to the next attached image.
 */
function athemes_the_attached_image() {
    $post                = get_post();
    $attachment_size     = apply_filters( 'athemes_attachment_size', array( 1200, 1200 ) );
    $next_attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url();

    /**
     * Grab the IDs of all the image attachments in a gallery so we can get the
     * URL of the next adjacent image in a gallery, or the first image (if
     * we're looking at the last image in a gallery), or, in a gallery of one,
     * just the link to that image file.
     */
    $attachment_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'numberposts'    => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order ID'
    ) );

    // If there is more than 1 attachment in a gallery...
    if ( count( $attachment_ids ) > 1 ) {
        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
            if ( $attachment_id == $post->ID ) {
                $next_id = current( $attachment_ids );
                break;
            }
        }

        // get the URL of the next image attachment...
        if ( $next_id )
            $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $next_id );

        // or get the URL of the first image attachment.
        else
            $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( array_shift( $attachment_ids ) );
    }

    printf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="attachment">%3$s</a>',
        esc_url( $next_attachment_url ),
        the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false ) ),
        wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $attachment_size )
    );
}
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'athemes_posted_on' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints HTML with meta information for the current post-date/time and author.
 */
function athemes_posted_on() {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
    //if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) )
        //$time_string .= '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';

    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
    );

    printf( __( '<span class="posted-on">%1$s</span>', 'athemes' ),
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( get_permalink() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            $time_string
        )
    );
}
endif;

/**
 * Returns true if a blog has more than 1 category
 */
function athemes_categorized_blog() {
    if ( false === ( $all_the_cool_cats = get_transient( 'all_the_cool_cats' ) ) ) {
        // Create an array of all the categories that are attached to posts
        $all_the_cool_cats = get_categories( array(
            'hide_empty' => 1,
        ) );

        // Count the number of categories that are attached to the posts
        $all_the_cool_cats = count( $all_the_cool_cats );

        set_transient( 'all_the_cool_cats', $all_the_cool_cats );
    }

    if ( '1' != $all_the_cool_cats ) {
        // This blog has more than 1 category so athemes_categorized_blog should return true
        return true;
    } else {
        // This blog has only 1 category so athemes_categorized_blog should return false
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Flush out the transients used in athemes_categorized_blog
 */
function athemes_category_transient_flusher() {
    // Like, beat it. Dig?
    delete_transient( 'all_the_cool_cats' );
}
add_action( 'edit_category', 'athemes_category_transient_flusher' );
add_action( 'save_post',     'athemes_category_transient_flusher' );
```

Comment: can you show what you have in the template-tags.php :)

Comment: There you have it! Newbie here, sorry!

Comment: I wonder if it might be related to other sections of the code. I just don't know why the original code simply doesn't work any longer.

Comment: Well, `printf` expects the first argument to be the format string (http://php.net/printf), so I suspect you may have deleted something inadvertently...

Comment: Nope, I paste it directly from the zip file and still doesnt work. I'm thinking of instaling the theme back again.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted and uploaded the theme file via ftp and everything is just fine now.